# view cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, file, onclick

what seems to be the problem with view here? how do i solve it?

the error "View cannot be resolved to a type"

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    Object o = my_listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
    // write you handling code like...
    String st = "sdcard/";
    File f = new File(st+o.toString());
    // do whatever u want to do with 'f' File object
    Log.d("The position fo f:",o.toString());
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: at which line it showing error..!!

Comment: can u paste the exact error ur getting

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should import it. If you are using Eclipse, press Ctrl+Shift+o.

Comment: (or cmd+shift+o if you just so happen to be using a mac)

Answer (score 4):

import.view.View

Sometimes If the API level specified in your manifest is below API level 12 then eclipse does'nt suggest this import. Might be because its not supported. But you can manually insert the import. The functions that require a higher API level won't work.