# ResponseEntity cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, httpresponse

I tried to add ResponseEntity<> in my rest endpoint class(spring boot project), where it does not allow me to add and I got a compilation error as "ResponseEntity cannot be resolved to a type". Please let me know why I'm not able to add them into my project.

Also I would like to know the ways for handling http status codes in response?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [view cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512557/view-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Answer (score 1):

How you init your ResponseEntity ?

You can do something like this :

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: This will have no effect. Since the problem is during the compilation, this too will give the same error. The problem is dependencies are not present at compile time.

Comment: Do you have  annotation     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> ?

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question

Comment: These are my dependencies I have added and not able to resolve the problem

Comment: I have added spring-boot-starter-web,spring-boot-starter-jdbc,spring-boot-starter-parent and mysql-connector-java . though having these dependencies, it is still showing ResponseEntity and also jdbcTemplate cannot be resolved to a type .

Answer (score 0):

You need to have

`implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'`

dependency in your `build.gradle` for including `ResponseEntity<T>`

Then, you can use it like

```
public ResponseEntity<String> getResponseEntityDemo(){
    return new ResponseEntity<>("This is the body", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: I have already added this dependency, but still not working.

Comment: Please add your build.gradle file